# react and styled component to change BG Color of Navitem using useState

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, use-state

enter image description here I want that when I clicked on a particular Navbar item it changes its BG Color and maintains the state of BG color until I route to another Navbar item. I'm a beginner to React and Styled-Component.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yNxK.png)

It reacts side code I want to change the color of navItemLink when it is clicked as active

```
enter code here

    <NavItem>
        <NavItemLink to="/">Invoices</NavItemLink>
        <NavItemLink to="/estimates">Estimates</NavItemLink>
        <NavItemLink to="/clients">Clients</NavItemLink>
        <NavItemLink to="/items">Items</NavItemLink>
        <NavItemLink to="/settings">Settings</NavItemLink>
   </NavItem>
```

Comment: could you provide the details of the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Thank you @SubratoPatnaik for your time and attentions towards my problem.But I have solved it myself.

Comment: You can answer your question so that others can know about this.

Comment: I have used <NavItemLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active">
                Invoices
              </NavItemLink>
              <NavItemLink to="/estimates" activeClassName="active">
                Estimates
              </NavItemLink>

Comment: <NavLink> and <NavItemLink> are same or different? What's the difference if there are different?

Comment: <NavItem> is just a div with some style, hover and active class